# ParseQuery PHP SDK how to modify other user data

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am using parse PHP SDK, I want to update user data using administrator user. I am trying to update user information like this my code:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("_User");
$query->equalTo("username", "nanu44");
foreach ($result as $doc) {
    $doc->set('name', "new info");
    $doc->save();
}
```

But it is giving me an error that can not modify user data.
Please suggest me

Answer (score 2):

The [Parse PHP documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/#security-for-other-objects) says:

> Data stored in a ParseUser can only be modified by that user. By default, the data can still be read by any client.

A possible solution is to use your master key to override this security measure by doing

`$doc->save(true)` [(documentation here)](http://parseplatform.github.io/parse-php-sdk/classes/Parse.ParseObject.html#method_save),

or to edit User ACLs so you have write access to other users, though I'm not 100% sure this is possible with the `User` class; see the first link for more details.